# How to determine the 'data-role' of a dom element

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a function that changes a dom element's text to a given value, for example, to change the text on the following:

```
<a id="btnAdd" href="#" onclick='Persist()' data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Persist</a>
```

I need to use this code:

```
domElement.find('.ui-btn-text').text('testing');
```

As you can see, I need to call `.find('.ui-btn-text')`. Is there a way to determine the 'data-role' (in this case 'button') so I can use the correct "thing" (e.g. '.ui-btn-text') to use - I think this is referred to as a CSS class?, not sure.

Unfinished Function:

```
        function SetDomElementText(elementId, value) {
            //get the domElement
            var domElement = $('#' + elementId);

            //check if it exists
            if (domElement.length === 1) {

                switch(domElement.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'label':
                        domElement.text('testing');
                        break;
                    case 'a': //link
                        //I need to determine what the data-role is here.
                        domElement.find('.ui-btn-text').text('testing');
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get it just like you're getting any other HTML attribute.

```
var datarole = $(selector).attr('data-role');
```

Alternatively, jQuery also picks up `data-*` attribute values automatically, so you can access it via `.data()`:

```
var datarole = $(selector).data('role');  // data-role
```

Comment: I didn't konw about the .data('...'). I always used .attr('data-...'). Thanks!

Comment: Thanks.. it's also SO SIMPLE when you know the answer :)

Comment: Nah, we all have our `d'oh!` moments. HAHA. :D